# How can I fix the combinatorial loop alert in Vivado?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, system-verilog, vivado

```
always @ (state, count)
    begin
      if(st_rst == 1'b1)
      begin
        state <= 3'b101;
        count <= 0;
      end
      else
      begin
        state <= next_state;
        count <= count + 1;
      end
        case(state) 
        3'b101://reset & initialize
        begin
            mem_rst =1'b1;
            dis_rst =1'b1;      
            pe_rst = 1'b1;
            three_rst = 1'b1;
            two_rst = 1'b1; 
            next_state = 0;
            two_end = 1'b0;
            s_end_1 = 1'b0;
            s_end_2= 1'b0;
            s_end_3 = 1'b0;
            s_end_4 = 1'b0;
    
            s3_end_22 = 1'b0;
            s3_end_21 = 1'b0;
            s3_end_12 = 1'b0;
            s3_end_11 = 1'b0;
            en_dis = 1'b0;
           //etc...
    end
```

> [DRC LUTLP-1] Combinatorial Loop Alert: 1 LUT cells form a
> combinatorial loop. This can create a race condition. Timing analysis
> may not be accurate. The preferred resolution is to modify the design
> to remove combinatorial logic loops. If the loop is known and
> understood, this DRC can be bypassed by acknowledging the condition
> and setting the following XDC constraint on any one of the nets in the
> loop: 'set_property ALLOW_COMBINATORIAL_LOOPS TRUE [get_nets
> <myHier/myNet>]'. One net in the loop is cont/st_rst_0. Please
> evaluate your design. The cells in the loop are:
> cont/s3_end_22_reg_i_4.

This is my part of my code, and the combinational loop occurred due to `always @ (state, count)`.

I want to make controls when the `count` and `state` values change. How can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

In the abbreviated code sample you show, this line is the cause of the combinational loop message:

```
    count <= count + 1;
```

The following line infers combinational logic:

```
always @ (state, count)
```

You should create another `always` block for your counter.  For example, this infers sequential logic (not combinational logic):

```
always @ (posedge clk or posedge st_rst) begin
    if (st_rst) begin
        count <= 0;
    end else bgein
        count <= count + 1;
    end
end
```

You should remove `count` from your other `always` block.

This means that you also need to add a clock signal to your design (`clk`), if you don't already have one.

You should also separate the `state` logic into another sequential `always` block.  Using several `always` blocks is a good practice to partition your logic; it often results in code which is easier to understand and maintain than trying to place all your code into a single block.

Also, it is better to use the implicit sensitivity list for combinational logic instead of explicitly adding signals (like `state`) to the list.  Change:

```
always @ (state, count)
```

to:

```
always @*
```